# Consulta de Combox

Tags: vb.net, combobox

¿Alguien me podría ayudar a ocultar el elemento de un `ComboBox` una vez que lo seleccionan y no perder el index interno para los demás elementos?

Mi `ComboBox` lo cargo con el siguiente método.

```vb
Private Sub ListarPeriodo()
    Dim _lista As New List(Of Integer)
    Dim producto As New Producto
    producto.Id = cmbProducto.SelectedIndex + 1

    Dim periodo As Integer = mgestorPeriodo.BuscarPeriodo(producto)

    For i As Integer = 0 To periodo - 1
        _lista.Add(i + 1)
    Next

    For Each i As Integer In _lista
        cmbPeriodo.Items.Add(i)
    Next
End Sub
```

El combo lo utilizo para cargar una cantidad determinada de números. Cuando el usuario seleccione un número determinado de este elemento, tiene que desaparecer y seguir con el siguiente número del combo. Pero no deben perder el índice, ya que cuando grabo el objeto, envía el índice de cada elemento.

Comment: *Alguien me podría ayudar ha ocultar el elemento de un ComboBox una vez que lo seleccionan y no perder el index interno para los demas elementos*: No entiendo lo que esto quiere decir. ¿Puedes dar un ejemplo concreto para que se pueda entender mejor?

Comment: Hola, el combo lo utilizo para carga una cantidad determinada de numeros. Cuando el usuario seleccione un numero determinado de este elemento tiene que desaparece y seguir con el siguiente numero del combo pero no deben perder el indice. Ya que cuando grabo el objeto enviar el indice de cada elemento.

Comment: Le faltan detalles a tu pregunta, en especial donde es que quieres programar la acción de ocultar. Por otra parte el objeto Combobox no permite ocultar un item, aunque si permite deshabilitarlo o habilitarlo (*enabled*). Deberías repensar si quieres y es llanamente necesario utilizar un combo o puedes utilizar otro control como DataGrid y Datatables. A fin de cuentas una solucion con combo deberia ser con Datatables internos también. Intenta explicarte más y colocar más código asi podremos ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

La que deseas es que cuando se selecciona por única vez uno de los valores del ComboBox se oculte el dicho valor seleccionado.

Es decir, si selecciono el valor `= VALOR B` que su index es `= 2`, debería ocultarse dicho valor `= VALOR B`; y tus demás valores e index deberían mantenerse.

```
INDEX | VALOR
1       VALOR A
2       VALOR B
3       VALOR C
4       VALOR D
5       VALOR E
```

Lo que harías es remover el valor ya seleccionado y mantener en un arreglo el index del valor seleccionar para poder manipular o hacer lo que quieras hacer con ese index, y luego vuelves a cargar o refrescar el ComboBox excluyendo el valor seleccionado. Lo puedes hacer desde la aplicación o desde la base de datos, tu select estaría con un valor en el where de manera dinámica.

Comment: ¡Gracias por tu aporte! ¿Podrías incluir un ejemplo de código que responda a la pregunta? La idea es sumar respuestas al sitio con la mayor calidad posible. Pensemos en alguien que recién se inicia en esto y se encuentra con este mismo problema, buscando resolver y entender por qué o cómo funcionan las cosas. Quizás un muy breve fragmento de código haría toda la diferencia. De lo el contrario, parecería un comentario, y no una respuesta.